# Trying to understand how different ways of input happen in C however the fgets() tends to skip

Tags: c, input, fgets

I am new to C and trying to learn how different inputs work. I wrote the this code to try getChar(), sscanf(), and fgets(). My first fgets() works perfectly fine but it skips the second one after I ask the user to enter a date. Am I using these functions in a way they are not supposed to be used. What are possible ways to solve this.

Also are there any other ways of receiving user input that would be more beneficial given certain scenerios.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 12
#define MAX_DATE 100

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char buf[MAX];
    char date[MAX_DATE];
    char day[9], month[12];
    int year;

    printf("This code shows various ways to read user input and also how to check for input\n");

    printf("Enter a String less than 11 characters for input: ");
    fgets(buf, MAX, stdin); //stdin is used to indicate input is from keyboard

    printf("Enter a char: ");
    char inputChar = getchar(); //gets next avalible char

    printf("\nThe char you entered is: "); putchar(inputChar); //puts char prints a char

    printf("\nsscanf allows one to read a string and manupilate as needed.\n");
    printf("\nEnter a date as follows: Day, Month, Year");

    fgets(date, MAX_DATE, stdin);
    sscanf(date, "%s, %s, %d", day, month, &year);

    printf("\nFormatted values as follows... \n");
    printf("day: %s\n", day);
    printf("month: %s\n", month);
    printf("year: %d\n", year);

    return 0;
}
/*
Output for the code:
This code shows various ways to read user input and also how to check for input
Enter a String less than 11 characters for input: hey
Enter a char: a

The char you entered is: a
sscanf allows one to read a string and manupilate as needed.

Enter a date as follows: Day, Month, Year
Formatted values as follows... 
day: 
month: 
year: -1205589279
Program ended with exit code: 0
*/
```

Comment: Tip: Avoid mixing `fgets()` with `scanf(), getchar()` until you know why its best avoided.  Likewise, avoid `scanf()`, (`sscanf()` us OK), until you know why its best avoided.

Comment: Also note that getchar() returns an int, not a char.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `fgets` is not being skipped. It is getting the rest of your line.

In your example, when prompted by "Enter a char: ", you are entering "a" followed by a newline. `getchar` gets the "a" character. `fgets` starts at the character directly after that, meaning it is reading the newline after the "a" and returning.

If you call `fgets(buf, MAX, stdin);`  after your `getchar()` to discard the rest of the line, your program will work as you expect.

Comment: If after `printf("Enter a char: "); char inputChar = getchar();`, the user enters `"\n"`, calling `fgets(buf, MAX, stdin);` would not be a good idea.

Comment: True, but this is a beginner program where safety isn't an issue. I was just trying to  explain why the program isn't working with explaining line buffering, input checking, checking `sscanf`'s return value, etc. I thought that would only add to the confusion for someone who is just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

[@contrapants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952769/2410359) nicely explains the reason for the "skips the second one".  When the user types <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `'a'` is read by `getchar()` and the `'\n'` is then read by `fgets()`, without waiting for additional input.

For a learner, I recommend to only use `fgets()` for input.

```
 printf("Enter a char: ");
 fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
 char inputChar = 0;
 sscanf(buf, "%c", &inputChar);
```

---

> Am I using these functions in a way they are not supposed to be used.

A side issue occurs when reading into a buffer without insuring no overflow.  Use width limits.

```
char day[9], month[12];
//sscanf(date, "%s, %s, %d", day, month, &year);
int count = sscanf(date, "%8s , %11s , %d", day, month, &year);
if (count != 3) {
  Handle_unexpected_input_somehow();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to implement this but I have still not come to understand why the fgets that are being put back to back skip each other. For Example I tried this printf("Enter smallest operator: ");
    fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
    smallestOpperatorChar = input[0];
    
    printf("Enter largest operator: ");
    fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
    largestOpperatorChar = input[0]; But it still skips the first fgets and does not ask me for an input and just jumps to "Enter largest Opperand"

Comment: @UlucOzdenvar Does you code use `scanf()` or `getchar()` prior to the first `fgets()`? - that is the problem as those did not consume all the line.